# How to pause a java program in eclipse by code

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any java code, which can make a java program pause in eclipse debugger, just like breakpoint? Then I can check the information of debugger, like values, stack.
Someone may misunderstand my question. I often write code for debugging like this

```
if(some_condition){
    print_log();
    abort();
}
```

In Visual Studio, I write abort() function. When I run a program in debug mode, abort() function can make the program pause and I can check the debugger.Is there some function in java like abort() in C++?

Comment: Any specific reason for having this kind of behaviour?

Comment: So debugger is already there with break points.Why u require this ?

Comment: Why don't you just place a breakpoint where you need it to stop?

Comment: My guess is he wants a conditional breakpoint - so the program itself can decide to pause. Not unreasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to use `conditional breakpoints`. I guess you don't want to define a beakpoint which will block your program each it passes on a given line, but only when specific condition occur.

So define a breakpoint, and add a boolean condition to it. You may for example define some variable like :

```
boolean must_break = false;
```

Then later on

```
if (some_condition) { must_break = true; }
```

Just set you breakpoint on any line with

```
must_break=false
```

That way, you control when you want to break you program's execution, and the `must_break` condition is reset for the next time.

Comment: This is a method. But I don't know whether configuring the condition breakpoint is as convenient as abort() function in C++. I have edited my question. Thanks for your answer!